# FluentAssertions: Assert all object properties are different from another object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, fluent-assertions

Is there any way to assert that all properties of *objectA* are different from all properties of *objectB* using FluentAssertions? *objectA* and *objectB* are instances of the same class.

`.BeEquivalentTo()` checks if any of the property is different. I'm looking for the same check that passes only if both objects have no equal properties and fails if at least one property is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. I recommend requesting an improvement at https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues

Comment: Asked [a feature request for that now](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/2289) as it apparently really is not possible as [I have had the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77025806/throw-on-additional-members-in-source-object-with-fluentassertions-which-are-not).